# switching content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a single page web application.I have taken four list elements Home,About us,Gallary,Contact us.After that there are four divs with id home,gallary,about and contact

```
 <div id="navigation">
 <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/gallary">Gallary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/contact">Contact US</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="home">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">HOME</h3>
    text of home goes here......
 </div>
 <div id="about">
 <h3 style="text-align:center;">ABOUT US</h3>
 Text for about us goes here.
 </div>
 <div id="gallary">
 <h3 style="text-align:center;">GALLARY</h3>
 <img src="slide1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
 </div>
 <div id="contact">
 <h3 style="text-align:center;">CONTACT US</h3>
 Phone:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
 Mobile:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
 Email:DD@CC.com<br>
 Fax:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
 </div>
```

The css for this is given bellow.Initially the div with id home is shown and other div are not displayed.

```
 #home
{
width:74%;
height:16%;
margin-left:13%;
border:solid black thin;
margin-top:2em;
position:absolute;
}
#about
{
width:74%;
height:16%;
margin-left:13%;
border:solid black thin;
margin-top:2em;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
#gallary
{
width:74%;
height:16%;
margin-left:13%;
border:solid black thin;
margin-top:2em;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
#contact
{
width:74%;
height:16%;
margin-left:13%;
border:solid black thin;
margin-top:2em;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
```

Now if i click on home then div with id home will display similarly if i click on About Us the div with id about is displayed so is with Gallary and contact.so i want to know how i can do this using jquery effects like slideup fadein etc.And also i want that when i press backspace button on keyboard or on browser the previous div should get loaded.I tried using change hash but i was not successful.To understand my problem better u can see the demo that what actually i want to ask.
Also if some one can give jsfiddle for this problem.
http://navi.grantcr.com/#!/home

Comment: I do not understand your exact problem. Please narrow it down.

Comment: http://navi.grantcr.com/#!/home visit this link

Comment: Please show us your effort.

Comment: Do u think it was a school..?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one,

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

         $(".navi").click(function(){

              $("#home,#about,#gallary,#contact").hide();
                var ToNav = $(this).attr('href');
                var Link =  ToNav.split("#!/");
                $("#"+Link[1]).show();

         });


    });
    </script>


    <div id="navigation">
     <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#!/home" class="navi" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/about" class="navi" >About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/gallary" class="navi" >Gallary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/contact" class="navi" >Contact US</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="home">
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">HOME</h3>
        text of home goes here......
     </div>
     <div id="about" style="display:none;">
     <h3 style="text-align:center;">ABOUT US</h3>
     Text for about us goes here.
     </div>
     <div id="gallary" style="display:none;">
     <h3 style="text-align:center;">GALLARY</h3>
     <img src="slide1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
     </div>
     <div id="contact" style="display:none;">
     <h3 style="text-align:center;">CONTACT US</h3>
     Phone:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
     Mobile:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
     Email:DD@CC.com<br>
     Fax:xxxxxxxxxx<br>
     </div>
```

Comment: Did you use my same code ? You just copy this code and paste it in a new file and run. It definitely works.

Comment: ya its working but the problem is that when i press back space the previous content content should load and the current content shoul dissappear